Is a buck-boost converter good enough as circuit protection for an automotive application?
I am designing a circuit for a automotive application that requires a stable regulated 12V supply. The supply in turn must be powered by an automotive battery.
I am currently looking at using a automotive-rated buck-boost converter such as the TPS552882-Q1 as my 12V supply source. My question is would the converter by itself already handle any under/over voltage conditions? For example, the converter linked is rated between 2.7V and 36V which covers the range of typical automotive conditions.
Is the buck-boost enough or do I need to pursue additional mitigations such as TVS's, crowbar, or other related circuit-protection devices? If so, why are these additional mitigations needed?

Personal or commercial product? Also, although more recent vehicles often include circuitry to reduce the impact of load dumps, older vehicles do not. And these can well exceed 100 V.

@periblepsis It is a personal product, but also going into an older vehicle (1989)

Start with this Wiki page and a quick google search also found this TI pdf appnote.


Is the buck-boost enough or do I need to pursue additional mitigations such as TVS's, crowbar, or other related circuit-protection devices? If so, why are these additional mitigations needed?

Short answer: Yes, you need other mitigations.  Reason: speed.  The buck-boost is too slow to deal with the very fast voltage transients, which are in the nanosecond range.

I know that TVS's can be good at responding to fast transients. How can I figure out the range of times that my buck-boost can handle to ensure I don't have a gap when selecting a TVS.

If this is just a personal project then I wouldn't be too concerned.  However, if this is a commercial product, then protecting this product from being damaged, or causing damage, or worse: causing harm to a person as a consequence of suffering a foreseeable voltage transient, then you do really need to spend significant design effort on these mitigations.  This is beyond the scope of this answer.
